# No Sound on Mac

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mac, rhythmbox

I installed the latest Ubuntu on a 2017 Imac.  Not a virtual machine - Ubuntu is the only operating system.  Since install there has been no sound.  The sound setting is set to speakers and when sound is played the bar lights up following the sound.  However nothing is heard.  The volume is high, not on mute.  I have installed pulse audio and again when sound is played through rhythmbox sound is detected and the purple bar flashes in time with it.  However nothing is heard from the speakers.  Any ideas?  I have viewed Alsa through terminal and the sound bars are on and coloured to the red level.

Comment: A search on this site for no sound on Mac gives 171 posts maybe one of them will help you. Always best to search before asking so you are not repeating an asked question. A duplicate question might just get deleted by the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/q/1464550/124466